# How to get values based on column index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have 2 dfs like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'aa', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
                    'Y': ['b', 'bb', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                    'Z': ['c', 'c', 'cc', 'c', 'c']})
```

Values in df are column indexes from df2. I want to get values from df2 based on numbers in df that are actually column indexes. How to do that? Expected outcome:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'aa', 'cc', 'c'],
                    'B': ['b', 'bb', 'b', 'c']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop to `numpy`'s level and use [multidimensional index slicing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html)

```
>>> arr = df2.values[np.arange(len(df)).reshape(-1, 1), df.values]
```

---

```
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['aa', 'bb'],
       ['cc', 'b'],
       ['c', 'c']], dtype=object)
```

Of course you wrap the result in `pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)` to get the final result you want.

```
    A   B
0   a   b
1  aa  bb
2  cc   b
3   c   c
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use applymap method twice to apply lambda functions to each element of df and df3. The first lambda function selects the corresponding column of df2 using the index value in df. This returns a numpy array of values. The second lambda function converts each numpy array to a pandas Series.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 2], 
                'B': [1, 1, 1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'aa', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
                    'Y': ['b', 'bb', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 
                    'Z': ['c', 'c', 'cc', 'c', 'c']})

df3 = df.applymap(lambda x: df2.iloc[:, x].values)
df3 = df3.applymap(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
df3.columns = df.columns
df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df3)
```

Comment: Tip: `applymap` is very slow, especially when the func you apply is `pd.Series` inside the `lambda`. For small dfs, this will run fast, but will get slow very very fast for big dfs ;)

Comment: That's definitely true - applymap can be slow when applied to large DataFrames. In this case,instead of using applymap to select columns from df2, you could use the loc method with a boolean mask to select the columns directly or use numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert `df2` to numpy and use `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df2.to_numpy()[range(len(x)),x])
```

or:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df))[:,None],df.to_numpy()],columns = df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   a   b
1  aa  bb
2  cc   b
3   c   c
```